# Can deadlock occur in this code snippet and why?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is deadlock possible in the following code snippet:

```
void f()
{
    {
        std::lock_guard <std::mutex> inner (lock1);
        // do something and conditionally return
    }
    std::lock_guard <std::mutex> outer (lock2);
    // do something
}
```

IOW, if multiple threads call this function, can a deadlock occur?

I am not too sure so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking **if** of **why** a deadlock can occur?

Comment: Are you asking if it is theoritically possible to cause a deadlock with your code or are you saying a deadlock occurs and you want to know why ? Also, provide a [minimum complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code is incomplete as it is not specified how `lock1` and `lock2` are created or how the threads are created.

Comment: I am asking if a deadlock can theoretically occur.

Comment: In the code posted no deadlock is possible. You are only ever holding a single lock.

Comment: Whenever you lock something, a deadlock is possible. While this listing on its own looks okay, some other function `g()` may acquire `lock1` or `lock2` and never release it. This will cause a deadlock of `f()` too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you refactor your code so each scope is a function, it become clears that the locks are never locked at the same time by a single thread :

```
std::mutex lock1;
std::mutex lock2;

// One mutex in g => No deadlock possible
void g()
{
    std::lock_guard <std::mutex> inner (lock1);
    // do something
}

// One mutex in h => No deadlock possible
void h()
{
    std::lock_guard <std::mutex> outer (lock2);
    // do something 
} 

// No mutex in f => No deadlock possible
void f()
{
    g();
    h();
}
```

From this you can conclude that when a thread is a requesting a lock, it does not hold one. This makes deadlock impossible.
You can check this yourself by creating a [BasicLockable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BasicLockable) object that simply wrap `std::mutex` and add a trace :

```
class PrinterMutex {
  public:
  PrinterMutex(const std::string& _name) : name(_name) {}
  ~PrinterMutex() {}
  void lock() {
    std::cout << "lock : " << name << std::endl;
    m.lock();
  }
  void unlock() {
    std::cout << "unlock : " << name << std::endl;
    m.unlock();
  }
  private:
    std::mutex m;
    std::string name;
};

PrinterMutex lock1("lock1");
PrinterMutex lock2("lock2");

int main()
{
    {
        std::lock_guard <PrinterMutex> inner (lock1);
        // do something and conditionally return
    }
    std::lock_guard <PrinterMutex> outer (lock2);
    // do something
}
```

The trace will show you that a thread will always release a lock before requesting one, making a deadlock impossible.

If you actually need multiple mutex in your code, you should use `std::lock` with multiple Lockable object to lock mutexes with deadlock avoidance algorithm.

```
std::mutex lock1;
std::mutex lock2;
void g()
{
        std::lock(lock1, lock2);
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> inner (lock1, std::adopt_lock);
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> outer (lock2, std::adopt_lock);
        // Do something
}
```

Comment: The lock are never locked at the same time so no deadlock is possible.

Comment: @Clonk You mean: never locked at the same time by the same thread.

Comment: @Clonk "the lock are never locked at the same time ...". You mean the LOCKS are never locked at the same time? Am I right? in addition, is there any theory in concurrency that if locks are not locked at the same time, no deadlock is happening? How you can conclude that?

Comment: @Gupta The point is was trying to explain (perhaps badly) was that no single thread can request a lock while currently holding one. This makes a deadlock impossible from a theoretical point of view since one of the necessary condition (see Coffman condition) is : `a process is currently holding at least one resource and requesting additional resources which are being held by other processes.` This condition cannot occur here.

Comment: @Clonk Good, so, I highly recommend you to add this point to your answer, with a reference to Coffman condition.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no. A fast explanation is that the locks are always acquired in the same order and there is no repetition (first `lock1`, then `lock2` if no `return` takes place).

Each thread first holds `lock1`. Whether the thread then conditionally returns or not does not matter. It does not try to acquire `lock2` while `lock1` is still held. In other words, `lock1` is always unlocked by a thread before that same thread tries to acquire `lock2`.

As @Gupta suggested, [here is a link](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/cplusplus/CON53-CPP.+Avoid+deadlock+by+locking+in+a+predefined+order) which describes how deadlocks can be avoided by locking in a predefined order.

Comment: If you can put a link to lock ordering mechanism, your answer will be more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

If the only two accesses to your two locks (`lock1`, `lock2`) are the ones shown in your code snippet (i.e. the locks are never accessed anywhere else), a deadlock can't happen, as the two locks are never locked simultaneously.

If the pair of braces around the `inner` lock guard weren't there, the two locks *would* be locked simultaneously, but since the order is always the same (first `lock1`, then `lock2`) deadlocks would still be impossible.

However, if `f` were to call some other function that might lock some other lock (especially via function pointer or virtual functions), or `f` would call itself recursively, a deadlock could happen (depending on the exact code).

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason this code can produce a deadlock.